# Downloading files from sharepoint programmatically C#

Tags: development, web-services, .net

I would like to know what are benefits/drawbacks when using either of these methods for downloading a document from Sharepoint

using Microsoft sharepoint library

```
public void Download(string serverFilePath, string destPath) {
    CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(Path.GetDirectoryName(destPath));
    using (FileInformation ffl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(_clientCtx, serverFilePath)) {
        using (Stream destFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(destPath)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = ffl.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                destFile.Write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as oposed to downloading it using WebRequest

```
public void DownloadFile(string serverFilePath, string destPath) {
    var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}", ServerURL, serverFilePath);
    CreateDirectoryIfNotExists(Path.GetDirectoryName(destPath));
    var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Credentials = _clientCtx.Credentials;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())) {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(destPath)) {
            sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

because using the HttpRequest results in approximately 30% better performance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't mean to nitpick but your first example is a really bad approach.  You are reallocating your buffer every iteration and using a truly tiny buffer at that.  Try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002834/saving-a-file-from-stream-to-disk-using-c-sharp) instead.